# Validation rule on Picklist value on Global Action

Tags: picklist, validation, tasks, global-actions

I have created a Global Action  'Log a Call Custom'

Here on the Task object I have a Picklist field Subject with four values -

'Please Select
'Option 1'
'Option 2'
'Option 3'

The default is 'Please Select'

I created a validation rule to prevent a user from saving the activity if the value in subject is 'Please Select'

This is my validation rule

ISPICKVAL (Subject, Please Select)

However i am getting a syntax error

**Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'**

what am i mising?

Comment: Single quotes around 'Please Select'

Comment: if i wrap 'Please select ' in single qotes i get different error
Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text

Comment: May be a better setup to just have 'Option 1', 'Option 2', and 'Option 3' for the possible selections and then select the Required checkbox which should enforce what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @TimHunter deleted my previous comment to you. Thanks for your suggestion!!. I only have 'Option 1',  'Option 2' , 'Option 3' . In the global action 'Log a call'  set the predefined field value to 'Please Select', and then added the validation rule to ensure user selects a value other than 'Please Select'.  Here i guess, selecting Required checkbox  become void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Subject= 'Please Select'.

As per documentation 'Subject' field datatype is combobox.

[Task Fields doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Task.htm)